# "Start Custom Task Process" Action Not Creating Task In Task List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365, designer-workflow, tasks

**Scenario:**

I have created simple list workflow in SharePoint designer. I have used `"Start Custom Task Process"` Action to create & assign the task to user.

Before Starting Task Process i am updating some fields in current item which are working fine.But whenever workflow comes to Task creation phase, workflow is showing `Error Occurred` status.

Even Task properties like "%Complete", "Form_URN", "Outcome" are also not showing in Task Process properties.

**Note:** I Have created same workflow in my test office 365 site which are working fine and creating the task. Also all task properties are available there. Problem is with our production Office 365 site.

**Similar threads:** (But nothing is helping)

[List wokflow not creating task](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin/list-wokflow-not-creating-task/7d893d19-3266-4fb7-8a66-59491654a11d)
[Sharepoint workflow not adding tasks to Workflow Tasks lists](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145297/sharepoint-workflow-not-adding-tasks-to-workflow-tasks-lists)
[SharePoint Designer Workflow Tasks Not Being Created](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/20de667d-a3e0-4394-b814-d7cf35ee541c/sharepoint-designer-workflow-tasks-not-being-created?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

**Details:**

Environment: Office 365
SP Designer: SPD 2013
Workflow Template: SP 2010

please help.